# docker-compose up doesn't build

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I am trying to build and run a golang app with docker-compose.
Here are my settings:

```
./docker/Dockerfile
./main.go
Makefile
```

Makefile

```
compose:
        env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 GOARM=7 go build
        cd docker && docker-compose up
```

./docker/Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.11

COPY app .
CMD ["./app"]
```

./docker/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    app:
        build:
            context: ../
            dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
        env_file: ./app.env
        ports:
            - '9292:8000'
```

I run the following command, expecting to build a new binary and run it inside a Docker container.

```
$make compose
```

It runs great, but if I run the same command after updating `main.go` the new binary isn't copied to docker container. The docker container seems to use the previous binary (i.e. the first binary that was copied when the container was first constructed).

Can someone explain why this is happening and what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

The key was to use `--build` option in `docker-compose up`.
I expected `docker-compose up` to rebuild every time, but it just starts the container once it has been built and created from before.

Comment: I guess you can mark this question as solved then. :)